# Adding images to class with time intervale between each image

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add stars (images) to a class with JS.

```
function putStars(){
if(test){
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var star = document.createElement("img");
        star.src = "star.png";
        var element = document.querySelector(".java");
        element.append(star);
    }
    test = false;
}
}
```

So as you can see I add images to the class Java, but what I want to do is adding images but a waiting effect between each image and not just a block of 5 images. 
I found the setTimeOut function but I'm not sut if it's the best way to do this.

Comment: You can also use `setInterval()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically replace your for-loop with `setInterval` like this to achieve a time delay between each iteration.

```
let i = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  i++;
  var star = document.createElement("img");
  star.src = "star.png";
  var element = document.querySelector(".java");
  element.append(star);

  if (i === 5) { clearInterval(interval); } // <- after 5 iterations clear the interval 
}, 1000); // <- this 1000 is 1 sec. delay
```

Although you can move `var element = document.querySelector(".java");` outside of the interval so that you don't search for it more than once since it is unnecessary.

```
let i = 0;
var element = document.querySelector(".java");

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  i++;
  var star = document.createElement("img");
  star.src = "star.png";
  element.append(star);

  if (i === 5) { clearInterval(interval); } // <- after 5 iterations clear the interval 
}, 1000); // <- this 1000 is 1 sec. delay
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setinterval this way, so your images will most likely already be loaded before you append them to your element.

```
const listToAppend = [];
const element = document.querySelector(".java");

const start = () => {
  let si = setInterval(()=>{
    if(listToAppend.length === 0){
       clearInterval(si);
       return;
    }
    element.append(listToAppend.shift());
  }, 1000);
}

function putStars(){
 if(test){
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var star = document.createElement("img");
        star.src = "star.png";
        listToAppend.push(star);
    }
    start();
    test = false;
 }
}
```